# Are virtual calls worth it for game entity management?

Tags: c++, entity-system

I have seen a lot of game programming tutorials doing this:

```
//our base class 
class entity 
{
   /*virtual methods and data common to all entities 
   and a 4 Byte virtual pointer*/
};

//Some other class inheriting those calls and data
class Player : public entity
{
   //extra methods and calls specific to class a 4 Byte virtual pointer
};
```

and thousands of Gameobject classes doing the same thing. What it does that it allows us to make a list of all objects and update and render (and some other things) it in a single loop.

But I have problems with this approach when I want to do something with a single object. suppose we have a list of all entities...

```
list<entities*> entities = {
new Player0(its properties),
new Enemy0(its properties),
new Player1(its properties),
new Stone0(its properties),
.... and so on
};
```

and now I want to stop updating Player1 for some reason. Now Either I can assign an ID to each object so that I can use "if" condition to stop updating it or I can have a reference to that object before pushing it to the list which is messy because I cannot have refrences to all of objects. Also lets consider that 4 byte additional size for those objects because of virtual calls.

An Alternative can be to have only references to objects...but again its thousands of objects we are talking about here so It will be hard to manage.

How to handle this problem?

Comment: Add a boolean `do_not_update` flag to the Player class and check it in `Player::update()`?

Comment: You should use component pool and update means iterating over the pools not over an array of Entity* and cast them or rely on virtual functions.